# How to pass variables in the 'action' attribute of a form?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to pass a variable inside the action attribute as shown

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/posts/{$post->id}/comments')}}">
```

The URL after submitting the form is this;

http://localhost/Laravel/public/posts/%7B$post-%3Eid%7D/comments

- 3Eid represents '->'

while the value of $post->id is supposed to be 30 in my case.

Can you please tell me the way to pass the value of `$post->id`?

Comment: Rather than passing it through the URL, I would pass it as a `input type="hidden"`.

Comment: In the future please use the relevant tags and make your title clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace ' with ":
`<form method="POST" action='{{url("/posts/{$post->id}/comments")}}'>`

Answer (score 1):

Change ' too "

so this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/posts/{$post->id}/comments')}}">
```

becomes

```
<form method="POST" action='{{url("/posts/{$post->id}/comments")}}'>
```

Only if you use the double quotes you can echo with {}